# SQL ERROR : Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 4 Incorrect syntax near ','

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to run this code:

```
SELECT 
    FIN AS 'LIN',
    CUSIP, 
    Borrower_Name, 
    Alias,
    DS_Maturity, 
    Spread, 
    Facility, 
    Facility_Size, 
    Log_date
FROM 
    [Main].[FacilityInformation]
WHERE 
    CUSIP IN ('00485GAC2', 'N1603LAD9')
    OR (YEAR(DS_Maturity) = (2019, 2024)
    AND ((Borrower_Name LIKE 'Acosta Inc , Bright Bidco BV%'
          OR Alias LIKE 'Acosta 9/14 (18.61) Non-Extended Cov-Lite, Lumileds 2/18 Cov-Lite%')))
```

But I got this error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
>   Incorrect syntax near ','

Between 2019 and 2024

I tried to modify this piece of code, with or without quotes and parenthesis, none of this worked. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 4):

Function `YEAR` returns `int`, so you need to write

```
YEAR(DS_Maturity) IN (2019, 2024)
```

or like this

```
YEAR(DS_Maturity) BETWEEN 2019 AND 2024
```

Comment: Oh  it worked. thank you @antihacker 2009. One more, I am having same issue with this code Borrower_Name LIKE 'Acosta Inc' ,'Bright Bidco BV%'

Comment: You should write like this:  Borrower_Name = 'Acosta Inc' or Borrower_Name like 'Bright Bidco BV%'

Answer (score 3):

Formatting your SQL with WhiteSpace and linebreaks makes for much easier reading. If you do that you get something like this:

```
SELECT FIN AS LIN,
       CUSIP,
       Borrower_Name,
       Alias,
       DS_Maturity,
       Spread,
       Facility,
       Facility_Size,
       Log_date
FROM [Main].[FacilityInformation]
WHERE CUSIP = ('00485GAC2', 'N1603LAD9')
   OR (YEAR(DS_Maturity) = ('2019','2024')
   AND ((Borrower_Name LIKE 'Acosta Inc , Bright Bidco BV%'
      OR Alias LIKE 'Acosta 9/14 (18.61) Non-Extended Cov-Lite, Lumileds 2/18 Cov-Lite%')));
```

Running that, you get the error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 12 Incorrect syntax near ','.

And line 12 is:

```
   OR (YEAR(DS_Maturity) = ('2019','2024')
```

You should be able to clearly see the problem is now (it should be `IN` not `=`).

Personally, however, I recommend against using `YEAR` in the `WHERE` as it makes the query non-SARGable. Instead use proper date and Boolean logic:

```
   OR ((DS_Maturity >= '20190101' AND DS_Maturity < '20200101')
   OR  ((DS_Maturity >= '20240101' AND DS_Maturity < '20250101')...)
```

Comment: Shouldn't the IN values be 2019, 2024 instead of strings since the YEAR function returns an int? But I agree 10000% about the sargability issue here. And extra +1 for removing the string literal in the alias!!!

Comment: Leaving it as `('2019','2024')` was more "laziness" on my behalf, @SeanLange. The values will be implicitly converted to an `int` anyway (as int has a high precedence) and SARGability had already be ruined by the `YEAR` function, so converting a literal `varchar` to an `int` is one of the lowest concerns for from a performance impact. But yes, strictly speaking they should be `int`s too.  I hadn't even noticed the `[Column] AS 'Alias'` (SQL Prompt gets rid of those for me), but at least it wasn't `'Alias' = [Column]`, which is deprecated.

Comment: I don't disagree at that it is a low importance. Just mentioning is so perhaps the OP will consider datatypes in the future. :P

Answer (score 1):

You have `=` where you should have `in`.  But the types are also wrong.  I would suggest:

```
SELECT FIN AS 'LIN', CUSIP, Borrower_Name, Alias,
       DS_Maturity, Spread, Facility, Facility_Size, 
       Log_date
FROM [Main].[FacilityInformation]
WHERE CUSIP IN ('00485GAC2', 'N1603LAD9') or 
      (YEAR(DS_Maturity) IN (2019, 2024) AND
       (Borrower_Name LIKE 'Acosta Inc , Bright Bidco BV%' OR
        Alias LIKE 'Acosta 9/14 (18.61) Non-Extended Cov-Lite, Lumileds 2/18 Cov-Lite%'
       )
      )
```

If you intend for that to be a range, you should either include all values in the range or use `BETWEEN`.

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
YEAR(DS_Maturity) = ('2019', '2024')
```

This is not valid syntax, you probably want the `IN` operator instead. Also, `YEAR()` return a number, not a string

```
YEAR(DS_Maturity) IN (2019, 2024)
```

Here is a new version of your query. Formating and indenting make it easier to understand the query and spot problems:

```
SELECT 
    FIN AS [LIN], 
    CUSIP, 
    Borrower_Name, 
    Alias,
    DS_Maturity, 
    Spread, 
    Facility, 
    Facility_Size, 
    Log_date
FROM [Main].[FacilityInformation]
WHERE 
    CUSIP IN ('00485GAC2','N1603LAD9') 
    OR (

        YEAR(DS_Maturity) = (2019, 2024)  
        AND (
            Borrower_Name LIKE 'Acosta Inc , Bright Bidco BV%' 
            OR Alias LIKE 'Acosta 9/14 (18.61) Non-Extended Cov-Lite, Lumileds 2/18 Cov-Lite%'
        )
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to use the BETWEEN Sql function?

```
SELECT FIN AS 'LIN',
       CUSIP,
       Borrower_Name,
       Alias,
       DS_Maturity,
       Spread,
       Facility,
       Facility_Size,
       Log_date
  FROM [Main].[FacilityInformation]
 WHERE CUSIP IN ('00485GAC2', 'N1603LAD9')
    OR (YEAR(DS_Maturity) BETWEEN 2019 AND 2024
        AND ((Borrower_Name LIKE 'Acosta Inc , Bright Bidco BV%'
             OR Alias LIKE 'Acosta 9/14 (18.61) Non-Extended Cov-Lite, Lumileds 2/18 Cov-Lite%')))
```

Comment: Hi @Gabriel. You are welcome. Please accept the answer so you can close the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the `=` with `IN` as you are having two values i.e. more than one with =